# Modal container with: auto centering, fitting size of content inside container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for some kind of modal container (for jQuery framework). I need this container support:

- fitting dimensions of content inside modal container; I will load container with data using ajax so some kind of dimensions recalculations required (as far as I understand)
- ater fitting content container should be centered and shown to user
- modal container should be shown on some kind of semi-transparent background (this "background" will block interacting user with another parts of page, focusing to modal container)
- lightwight, easy to customize (modal container html and css) etc.

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Answer (score 0):

I bealive jQuery ui dialog meets your expectations http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal